# Accessing specific values in array of JSON-Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, backbone.js

I am using rails 3 with backbone.js 0.53 and currently receive a GET with the following array:

```
[{"credit_card":
    {"id":2,"cc_number":"12345678912345","cc_type":"stack","owner":"overflow"}},
    ....next objects....]
```

I have read a lot of the other threads but can't figure out how to access the values.
Is there any way to do this with the backbone-given methods like .get()?

I tried

```
myArray = eval(arrayJSON)
alert myArray.length #works
```

but any other way of accessing the single values in an array or iterating over it fails.
Probably I am just missing something here.

Comment: What other methods have you tried?

Comment: tried to iterate over it with a for loop like myArray[i]. (=> not defined) and the backbone .each way but I guess this one only works when you have your JSON in a format like this {(val1), (val2)}

Comment: How are you fetching the data from the server? If eval works but nothing else it may be that you are loading the JSON with a response type of text.

Comment: I am passing the collection through the router to the view and then do @options.payments.fetch(success: callback) where payments fetches the available payment methods in the format of my post above. my request header for this has "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01" so it should be alright. Like I said the strange thing is that it gives me the correct .length() but I can't access the content: myArray[0] is undefined. JSON.parse() throws an "JSON.parse: unexpected character" but jsonlint.com tells me everything is valid.

Comment: Could it be the character encoding then? JSON has to be UTF-8. If you paste your JSON into jsonlint.com it may be converted. Otherwise I have no further idea what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick example of how to iterate through all your results via underscore:

```
/* received results mocking */

model.attributes = [
    { "credit_card" : { "id":2, "cc_number":"12345678912345" },
    { "credit_card" : { "id":3, "cc_number":"44444444455555" },
    { "credit_card" : { "id":4, "cc_number":"66666655554332" }
]

/* lets get all results */

results = model.toJSON()

/* loop through all results */

_(results).each(item) {
    console.log(item.credit_card.id);
}

/* get result by array pos */

console.log(results[1]); // get 2nd item
```

Cheers

Comment: absolutely crazy! can't loop through the array like I "normally" would and @David Brainer-Banker suggested but this way it is working. Thanks a lot! Would be really interesting if anyone has an explanation for this!!!

Comment: as for the syntax I use HAML. Probably helpful for anyone doing the same: _.each(results, (item) ->
          console.log(item.credit_card.id)
        )

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to see more details, but in general you should be able to access elements just fine with the following syntax: `alert(myArray[0].credit_card.cc_number);`

I even pasted your sample array into jsFiddle and had no issues: http://jsfiddle.net/P4w7T/1/